# MockitoSerializationIssue: A class couldn't be found while deserializing a Mockito mock

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mockito

I have trait *AWSClient* which shows that class extending it is AWSClient like SNSClint, S3Client..

```
trait AWSClient extends Serializable {
  def resourceType:String
}
```

One such class extending trait *AWSClient* is AWSS3Client

```
class AWSS3Client extends AWSClient {
  private lazy val s3Client: AmazonS3 = getS3Client("", "", "", Some(""))

  def uploadToS3(data: String): PutObjectResult = {
    s3Client.putObject("bucketName", "key", data)
  }
  override def resourceType: String = "s3"

  def getS3Client(accessKey: String, secretKey: String, region: String, KmsCmkId: Option[String]): AmazonS3 = {...}
}
```

I have a class which take instance of `AWSClient` extending client, DataFrame *data* and *sparkSession* as parameter. *publishData* method of class iterate over DataFrame *data* and publish data to passed client.

```
class PublishData(publishDataClient: AWSClient,
                       data: DataFrame,
                       sparkSession: SparkSession) extends Serializable {
  def publishData = {
    data.foreachPartition { dataSetPartition => {
      dataSetPartition.foreach(row => {
        val calculatedData: String = someOperation(row);
        PublishDataUtil.publishData(publishDataClient, calculatedData)
      })
    }
    }
  }

  def someOperation(row: Row): String = {
    // some dummy operation operation
    return "testdata"
  }
}

object PublishDataUtil extends Serializable {
  def publishData(publishDataClient: AWSClient, calculatedData: String) = {
    if (publishDataClient.resourceType.equals("s3")) {
      publishDataClient.asInstanceOf[AWSS3Client].uploadToS3(calculatedData)
    }
  }
}
```

Now to validate (run test cases on PublishData) I have created test class *PublishDataTest* and passed mocked AWSS3Client, i.e. *mockS3Client* in its constructor

```
class PublishDataTest extends FlatSpec
  with Matchers
  with MockitoSugar
  with SparkHelper
  with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  private val mockedPutObjectResult = Mockito.mock(classOf[PutObjectResult], Mockito.withSettings().serializable())
  private val mockS3Client: AWSS3Client = Mockito.mock(classOf[AWSS3Client], Mockito.withSettings().serializable(SerializableMode.ACROSS_CLASSLOADERS))
  when(mockS3Client.resourceType).thenReturn("s3")
  when(mockS3Client.uploadToS3(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(mockedPutObjectResult)

  "publishData" should "return nothing" in {
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val data = Seq(
      (1, 11, "stringData1"),
      (2, 22, "stringData2")
    ).toDF("id1", "id2", "stringData")

    new PublishData(mockS3Client, data, sparkSession).publishData
  }
```

When I am running test case, I am getting following exception:

```
[scalatest] - should return nothing *** FAILED *** (405 milliseconds)
[scalatest]   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoSerializationIssue:
[scalatest] A class couldn't be found while deserializing a Mockito mock, you should check your classpath. The error was :
[scalatest]   com.abc.poc.AWSS3Client$MockitoMock$610943276$auxiliary$nz6gzLcw
[scalatest] If you are still unsure what is the reason of this exception, feel free to contact us on the mailing list.
[scalatest]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[scalatest]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Versions:

```
Scala: 2.11
Spark: 2.2.1
ScalaTest = 2.2.x;
Mockito = 2.22.x;
ScalaMock-ScalaTest = 3.2.x;
```

Complete log: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13OvV9gBJ6HFRLnILEjYPmXZRSDXD-8p9N8ke6XlHpZQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems that you are marking classes as Serialisable that contain non-serialisable elements... is not in the error, but it may be the under-the-hood problem.

Comment: If PublishData gets an AWSClient why are you mocking AWSS3Client?

Comment: @fonkap for unit test, i don't want to use real AWSClient. So I want to mock its "uploadToS3" function in this case

Comment: I meant `trait AWSClient` which should be easier to mock than `AWSS3Client`.
Now reading the code more carefully I see the `asInstanceOf` casting and I understand why you need an `AWSS3Client` instance.
I think you could make an "intermediate" trait between `AWSS3Client` and `AWSClient`. I mean a trait `AWSS3ClientTrait`  that extends `AWSClient` that has`resourceType=="s3"`and a method `uploadToS3`. And mock this `AWSS3ClientTrait`. You also would need to refactor the code a little. `AWSS3Client`now will extend `AWSS3ClientTrait` and `publishData` will cast to this `AWSS3ClientTrait` also.

Comment: The idea is to mock the simplest possible class or trait to get rid of problematic parts, like `val s3Client: AmazonS3`